# Is there a way to shut off Mazda 6 after X minutes if it's parked and idling?

Tags: idle, mazda-6

My wife has a Mazda sport 6 2020. She sometimes forgets to press the button to turn the car off when she gets out. Are there any systems that can shut the car off after X minutes if it's parked and idling? Some cars have this built in. I checked with my Mazda dealer, and he said Mazda does not offer anything like this. Thanks.

Comment: Does it not have [stop-start](https://www.autocar.co.uk/car-news/new-cars/mazda-6-gets-advanced-stop-start)? It says introduced in 2013. OT: my Skoda was over-enthusiatic with stopping and would kill the engine (and the power steering) mid-manoeuvre. I disabled it by disconnecting its battery voltage detector. I know how to turn off the engine when it's not needed: there is a key to do that.

Comment: Did you verify that it does not auto shut off, say by parking it outside in a safe location and checking after 15-30 minutes? Often, these things are poorly documented or the dealer techs are too lazy to read the service manual.

Comment: My wife has verified that it does not shut off several times by getting to her car after work and realizing that it's been running for hours. 
It does not appear to have stop-start. I've never experienced it doing that, I can't find anything about it in the manual, and I've never found it going through the car's UI. It was purchased in the US.

Comment: [This Mazda 6 manual](https://owners-manual.mazda.com/gen/en/mazda6/mazda6_8ea5ee14k.pdf) published in 2016 says on page 165: "**i-stop**
The i-stop function automatically stops the engine when the vehicle is stopped at a traffic
light or stuck in traffic, and then restarts the engine automatically to resume driving.".

Comment: Stop-start wouldn't directly shut the vehicle off if it was equipped. The reason for that is there are several parameters which have to be present for it to shut the engine off. At least some of those are, the vehicle has to be in drive with the engine warmed up. Then it has to be at a full stop with the brake pedal depressed. Obviously the car was warmed up and at a full stop, but it's not in drive and no foot on the brakes. @WeatherVane ... it would seem to me you've got a serious problem with your vehicle's stop-start if it's working as you described, which sucks. Glad you got it remedied.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 haha, despite the bleepers and safety systems, it would happily drive away if I got out of the car with it accidentally left in reverse. Fortunately in reverse the steering goes to lock making it less prone to cause damage and easier to catch up with :) Apparently it knew if someone was in the passenger seat (to control the seat belt warning) but not the driver's seat.

Comment: There is no excuse of; parking and when stopped with brakes still applied, engaging the parking brake or not, and pressing the START/STOP button. Auto stop/start only works when brakes are applied while driving, not after parking since releasing the brake pedal automatically allows restarting.

Comment: The Mazda 6 manual for 2020 (https://www.mazdausa.com/siteassets/pdf/owners-optimized/2020/mazda6/2020-mazda6-owners-manual.pdf) which is the car I'm asking the question about does not contain "i-stop".

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is pretty simple. The start stop function has nothing to do with the problem. On some vehicles if you leave the vehicle with the engine running it will automatically shut of after a designated amount of time, usually around 15 minutes. This is controlled by the ECM or PCM. This car apparently does not have this function. You can confirm this by looking in the owners manual. The best solution is to be sure that the engine is turned off before exiting the car. It is a fundamental of operating a vehicle. The confusion is between the start stop function and the start stop button. The driver is responsible to push the stop start button to turn off the vehicle.

Answer (score -1):

There is no excuse of; parking and when stopped with brakes still applied, engaging the parking brake or not, and pressing the START/STOP button. How simpler can this get?

Auto stop/start works when brakes are applied while driving, coming to a stop sign or red light, not after parking since releasing the brake pedal automatically allows restarting.

Unless this woman learns a simple routine millions all over the world have already learned, you have one option; install an aftermarket alarm system equipped with a turbo timer to idle the engine using a turbocharger, timed for around 3-5 minutes then shutting down the engine. Decades ago, drivers learned the hard way of burning out their turbochargers after a hot drive, shutting down the engine while hot. Oil under pressure is fed to lube and provide cooling to very hot bearings. Immediate engine shutdown let's hot oil cook in place, resulting in coking where cooked oil residue forms on bearing surfaces, eventually leading to choked oil passages and an expensive replacement or rebuild. Turbo timers allow the lazy driver to walk away, leaving the engine idling for the few minutes for oil to circulate as the turbo cools off while the vehicle is locked, then the engine shuts down.

This rather lengthy explanation is to give you choices with the most common sense approach already given. If a person can remember to take house keys and phone, it should be easy to 'practice' pressing the auto START/STOP button after parking, before leaving the vehicle. Oh, and an easy tell tale is observing the engine tachometer; if its showing idle, under 900 rpm, the engine's still running. Shutting off the engine will drop the tach number to zero (0).

Comment: This won't work. Turbo timers require a positive action to start timing: they hold the ignition on _after_ the key has been switched off. If the irresponsible driver here were to switch off the ignition or be of mind to push some button to start the timer, then we wouldn't have this issue to begin with.

Comment: My turbo timer was part of DEI's remote start system. However, I never needed it in my non turbo'd engine so I never went into determining how to use it. DEI programmed remote start for a minimum of 10 minutes or more depending on driver desires before shutting down if the driver doesn't enter the vehicle and turn on ignition. My guess is the reverse in programming is used to allow engine idling before shutting down. You may be right about having to turn off ignition to have the turbo timer activate which, as you stated, goes against simplicity of remembering to turn off the engine.